# API to find Azure Subscription properties

Tags: azure

Is there an API or any other way to get the subscription properties (such as name, status etc...). I've found management APIs for hosted services and deployments, but failed to find any for subscriptions.

thanks,
Nava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same question, and looks like now there is an API for that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg715315.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no such API.